# How do you get the insights from custom actions

Tags: api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-insights

I've read this page, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/insights/, but I can't seem to tell how we can get the insight data for each of our custom actions we've created.

SO for example, we have 6 different custom actions, and would like to get the metrtics on all of them.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There is a post_stories_by_action_type api filter can be used.